# How to update text node of element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

---

#### My Code

I have this html

```html
​<a href="#">
    <i>[please keep this]</i>
    Some Text To Update
</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And this jQuery

```js
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).text('Updated Text');
    return false;        
});​
```

---

#### Problem

When the link is clicked I am getting:

```
<a href="#">Updated Text</a>
```

---

#### Desired Result

I want to preserve the `<i>` element and get this:

```
<a href="#"><i>[please keep this]</i> Updated Text</a>
```

**The HTML cannot be modified**

---

#### [play along on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naomi/at6qQ/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it is the following:

**Adding a span**:

```
<a href="#">
    <i>[please keep this]</i>
    <span class="replace">Some Text To Update</span>
</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​


$('a').click(function(){
    $('.replace', this).text('Updated Text');
    return false;
});​
```

Add your text inside a `span` and then update your span text.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/hekK5/)

**Without modify html**:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).html(function(i, text) {
        return text.substr(0, text.lastIndexOf('>') + 1) + 'Updated Text';
    });
    return false;
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/hekK5/1/)

**or**

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var $keep = $('i', this);
    $(this).empty().append($keep).append('Updated Text');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/hekK5/3/)

Comment: @naomik Now I have a third :)

Comment: Thanks again, Ricardo. I really like the `fn(i, text)` solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(){
var saveThis = $(this).children('i');

$(this).text('Updated Text').prepend(saveThis);
 return false;        
  });​
```

I'm assuming that the text to save will always be in an i tag

EDIT: Used prepend instead, now it works in jsfiddle. No HTML change necessary
EDIT: removed .clone per @Ariel

Comment: Why would you clone it and then use it in `text()`? Just grab the `text()` from it as a string and don't clone the node. And in any case you can't use dom elements that way in string concatenation.

Comment: edited for a better fix. Still using clone because I'm assuming we want to preserve the i tag itself with the content and the "Some Text to Update" is not constant. It works in the JSfiddle

Comment: You don't need clone. Use the original element directly - you don't need a copy of it.

Comment: Not the html of the original, the actual original dom element, so the tag is preserved. i.e. just remove `clone()` it doesn't nothing useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yah, that's not easy to do.

Best option is to wrap the part you want to change in a `<SPAN>`:

```
<a href="#">
    <i>[please keep this]</i>
    <span>Some Text To Update</span>
</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

$('a span').....
```

Second best option is to extract the `<i>` part and reuse it:

```
var i = $('i', this);
$(this).empty().append(i, ' Updated Text'));
```

Comment: I was about to suggest using a span, also the second option doesn't preserve the `<i>` tag

Comment: She said she cannot change the HTML

Comment: I can't change the original HTML :(

Comment: Ariel, I can't change the HTML to use a `<span>`.

Comment: @naomik There are two solutions listed, use the second one.

Comment: Ariel, the second one doesn't work because `$('i',this)` will be null after `$(this).empty()` is called...

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help..

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/